# Перебор всех возможных вариантов

Tags: алгоритм

Необходимо из множества символов составить все возможные комбинации размера n.

Например, для множества {1,2} ответом будет

11
12
21
22

А для множества {1,2,3} ответом будет

111
112
113
121
122
123
131
132
133
211
212
213
221
222
223
231
232
233
311
312
313
321
322
323
331
332
333

Comment: `n^n` *(7 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем наименьшую комбинацию - 111...11 - ну, сколько там надо.

И применяем следующий алгоритм получения следующей - берем самый правый элемент. Если его можно увеличить - увеличиваем, и получаем следующий. Например, для ваших 212 получим 213.

Если нельзя - он максимален - записываем вместо него минимальный и переходим к следующему справа. Типа для 213 - 221 (3 не увеличить - ставим 1, переходим к 1, увеличиваем до 2).

Все. Вот такой аналог сложения с переносом в вашей хитрой системе счисления, не более того...